# TYPO3 WYSIWYG editor don't resize the immage that I insert in a content

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am very new in TYPO3 world (I came from Joomla and WordPress) and I am finding a problem with its preinstalled WYSIWYG editor.

The proble is that when I inser a big immage into a content, if I resize it (so it will be smaller), it resize it but after that I save the content the immage automatically come back to having the original size and in the page have the original size and it is not resized

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: What do you mean by WYSIWYG editor? The Rich Text Editor? What kind of content element are you using? Text & Images? Images only? I know a bug where typo caches the first size you first entered onto an images content element and won't change it the next times you change it. Does the first change of size get applied?

Comment: @Wipster yes, I mean RTE editor. I have tryied both as Text and as Text & Images. 
What happen is that for example if in the RTE editor I put a big immage (for example 1050px X 1050 px) if I do: right click on the immage ---> Modify immage ---> and here I change the values og width and height in 500 px X 500 px, then I press the update button the immage seems resized but when I save the content (the page) the immage come back to the original dimension...is this the problem you were talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the path to the imagemagick installation is correct in the install tool section.

Check if you got this in the basic configuration section : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/411272Sanstitre.jpg

Comment: mybe this is the problem !!! In this section say to me: "No ImageMagick installation available" What have I to do? can you help me? Tnx so much

Comment: You have to install ImageMagick on your server. If it's already installed, you have to put the right path to the image magick directory in the install section (All configuration -> [im_path]), in my case, the path is /usr/bin/. Make sure to enable the use of Image Magick in All configuration -> [im]